# plist - NSMutableDictionary - 0x0

Tags: dictionary, plist, mutable

I have a problem:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"];
    NSString *settingPath = [[[NSString alloc] init] autorelease];
    settingPath = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:filePath] pathForResource:@"Root" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    plist = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:settingPath];
```

after this plist is nil, adress ist 0x0 ... but why ?
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is some code that should work OK:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Note that the plist must be valid, otherwise you will get a null value.

Also, note that you don't need to use alloc/init to create a variable if you're just going to overwrite its value in another call.

Comment: The question is a bit old, but yes. This did it some months ago for me :-)